# How to validate a condition in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am studying R end Data Science. In a question, I need to validate if a number in an array is even.

My code:

```
vetor <- list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

for (i in vetor) {
    if (i %% 2 == 0) {
      print(i)
    } 
}
```

But the result is a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In if (i%%2 == 0) { :
  a condição tem comprimento > 1 e somente o primeiro elemento será usado
```

Translating:

**The condition has a length > 1 and only the first element will be used.**

What I need, that each element in a list be verified if is even, and if true, then, print it.

In R, how can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wrapper for `list` is not needed

```
vetor <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

running the OP's code

```
for (i in vetor) {
    if (i %% 2 == 0) {
      print(i)
    } 
}

#[1] 2
#[1] 4
#[1] 6
#[1] 8
#[1] 10
```

These are vectorized operations.  We don't need a loop

```
vetor[vetor %% 2 == 0]
#[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

---

When we wrap the vector with `list`, it returns a `list` of `length` 1 and the unit will be the whole vector. The `for` loop in `R` is a `for each` loop and not the traditional counter controlled 3 part expression loop.  So, the `i` will be the whole `vetor` vector.

Because `if/else` expects a single element and not a vector of `length` greater than 1, it results in the warning message

Or if we want to store it in a `list` with each element of `length` 1, use `as.list`

```
vetor <- as.list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @akrun, it was exactly what I need to understand!

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down your code and dig into each step to see what happened ...

---

You should notice that `vetor` is a list, i.e.,

```
> vetor
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

In this case, the iterator `i in vetor` denotes the array in `vetor`, which can be seen from

```
> for (i in vetor) {
+   str(i)
+ }
 num [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Therefore, when you have condition `i%%2==0`, you are indeed running

```
> for (i in vetor) {
+   print(i %% 2 == 0)
+ }
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

which is not a single logic value as a condition for `if ... else ...` state. That is the reason you got the warnings.

---

Regarding the workaround, you can refer to [@akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67525689/12158757), which could help you a lot